# Laravel output from SQL validation when record not exists

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm learning `Laravel` and I have a question that I do not understand.

I'm using query builder to run my own queries and I don't really know how to return  error message when there is no record:

```
public function store()
    {
       $item = request()->validate([
           'item' => 'required|min:6|max:10'
       ]);

         $details = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('TABLENAME')->where('ITEMID', '=',  $item )->get();

         return view('itemdetails.create', compact('details'));
    }
```

So if `$details` is `null` I need to return message how to do that? Something like in `raw` `PHP`

```
if(empty($details))
{
throw new Exception('My text')
}
```

Or check in a `blade` file:

```
 @if (count($details) != 1)

        I don't have a record!

    @endif
```

I tried `firstOrFail` but looks like this is not working.

Is there any other ways (best ways)?

Answer (score 2):

In controller

```
     $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
               'item' => 'required|min:6|max:10'
            ]);             
     $details = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('TABLENAME')->where('ITEMID', '=',  $item )->get();
      if (!$details) {
           $validator->errors()->add('item', 'Item not found');
      }

       if ($validator->fails()) {
             return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
        }
    return view('itemdetails.create', compact('details'));
}
```

And in the view file

```
{{$validator->errors()->first('item')}}
```

Comment: The proper way of putting validation with laravel way like above.

Answer (score 1):

Just use normal if condition will do for Controller

```
if($details) //True
{
   //Redirect to..
}else
{
   //Redirect to..  //False
}
```

For blade you may use `@if(count($details))` if true it will display info `@else {{No data}} @endif`

Comment: Additional tips~You may use session flash to send and successful/error message too~